# What is the correct way to log PHP script's execution time and memory usage?

Tags: php, php-fpm, mrtg, collectd

I want to monitor the execution time and memory usage for my web application running on Nginx + FPM. To that end, I am generating execution time and memory data in the page footer. I can also insert this into the FPM error log file, to be read later :

`error_log("Performance Execution=$execution, Memory=$memory");`

The data obtained from the /var/log/php-fpm.log file is as follows:

```
raijin log # tail -f php-fpm.log | grep "Performance"
[02-Mar-2013 17:48:57] WARNING: [pool www] child 5546 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: Performance Execution=0.076794, Memory=11.276"
[02-Mar-2013 17:48:58] WARNING: [pool www] child 5547 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: Performance Execution=0.075967, Memory=11.276"
[02-Mar-2013 17:49:30] WARNING: [pool www] child 5548 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: Performance Execution=0.085233, Memory=11.276"
[02-Mar-2013 17:49:33] WARNING: [pool www] child 5549 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: Performance Execution=0.077445, Memory=10.672"
[02-Mar-2013 17:49:35] WARNING: [pool www] child 5546 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: Performance Execution=0.075163, Memory=10.044"
```

I want to collect this information and log it using something like [collectd](https://collectd.org/) or MRTG. So my question is :

1. Is there a better way to log performance details to be read later by collectd or MRTG?
2. How to pull this data into the logging programs?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/xhprof